# How to set default value for HTML select?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML select like this:

```
<select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

and I have a variable named `temp` in my JavaScript:

```
var temp = "a";
```

Now I want to set the value of the option that is equal to temp as default value for my select.

How can I do it?

Comment: I suppose you mean dynmically?

Comment: @InGodITrust: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Note: this is JQuery.  See Sébastien answer for Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    var temp="a"; 
    $("#MySelect").val(temp);
});

<select name="MySelect" id="MySelect">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 77):

You first need to add values to your `select` options and for easy targetting give the `select` itself an `id`.

Let's make option `b` the default:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>a</option>
    <option selected="selected">b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Now you can change the default selected value with JavaScript like this:

```
<script>
var temp = "a";
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');

for(var i, j = 0; i = mySelect.options[j]; j++) {
    if(i.value == temp) {
        mySelect.selectedIndex = j;
        break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Also we can use "text" property of i to validate:

if(i.text == temp)

See it in action on [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEVrVJ).

Comment: +1 for the most complete answer and working example provided!

Comment: +1 for using javascript; the "accepted" answer uses jQuery.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. The codepen has an error though - uses a , where it should have a ; this one works though http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEVjvr

Comment: Thank You for pointing this out @ovann86. I updated the codepen example.

Comment: Could you extend your answer for Html helpers?  For example:  @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.ReportId, New SelectList(Model.allReports, "ReportID", "ReportName", New With {.class = "form-control", .id = "ReportID"}), "Select Report....")

Answer (score 6):

You should define the attributes of `option` like selected="selected"

```
<select>
   <option selected="selected">a</option>
   <option>b</option>
   <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Simplay you can place HTML **select** attribute to option `a` like shown below

Define the attributes like `selected="selected"`

```
<select>
   <option selected="selected">a</option>
   <option>b</option>
   <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define attribute selected="selected" in 
Ex  a

Answer (score 0):

You could use...

```
<option <?= ($temp == $value) ? "SELECTED" : "" ?> >$value</opton>
```

Edit: I thought I was looking at PHP questions... Sorry.