# Change the default Select option using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am on an editing post page on wordpress and have this option to create a target link:

https://www.vtxfactory.org/images/11111.jpg

The default option is "None", I want it to be the "Custom Link..." one, for that, I have the following info:

```
<select name="imt_team_href" onchange="imtTeamCustomHref(this.value, '#imt_custom_href_div');">
<option value="-2">None</option>
<option value="-1">Custom Link ...</option>
<option value="2">Sample Page</option>

...
```

I know I could edit the file and add a "selected" code, but I can't find the file that needs to be edited.

I've tried but without success:

```
$(function() {
    $("#imt_custom_href_div").val("-1");
});
```

How can I, using javascript or whatever other method, change the predefined value?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set default value for HTML select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611557/how-to-set-default-value-for-html-select)

Comment: The solution provided on that post does not help.

Comment: That's because your `<select>` has no ID; you'll have to slightly modify to suit. There are **plenty** of examples there, and even that question is linked to [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element), which provides scores more approaches.

Comment: Yeah I know it doesnt have ID, but I don't have a way to assign one to it. Thanks, gonna check those out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector is wrong, it is looking for an ID but the `<select>` shown has no ID

Try

```
$('select[name="imt_team_href"]').val("-1");
```

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/6zknnrow/ Perhaps that element doesn't exist when page loads or there is other code affecting it

Comment: Hey, wordpress has some problems with javascript, so I had to change the code to this

jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('select[name="imt_team_href"]').val("-1");
});

And now its working, thanks :)

Comment: Ah yes...can avoid that problem by wrapping your jQuery code in `(function($){ /* code can use $ here*/})(jQuery)`

Comment: Is there a way to add the "selected" parameter to the "Custom Link ..." value?

Comment: Assigning the value will automatically set the `selected` property on that `<option>` ... try this after `alert($('select[name="imt_team_href"]').find(':selected').val())`

Comment: He did change the value to Custom Link but it appears that it didn't stay active, I'll try the code you provided now and I'll tell you something. Should I add that code next to the previous one?

Comment: It returns -1 as a message